# VBA Excel error on leaving textbox

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I thought of having a translucent text to show the format of how the date should be typed. After adding the code, I found out if I click on my txtA_DateCR textbox, and then clicked on another textbox or command button, the error will keep prompting out.

```
'This was the code that works fine before adding the following 2 below.
Private Sub txtA_DateCR_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Mid(txtA_DateCR.Value, 4, 2) > 12 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid date, make sure format is (dd/mm/yyyy)", vbCritical
        txtA_DateCR.Value = vbNullString
        txtA_DateCR.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    dDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
    txtA_DateCR.Value = Format(txtA_DateCR.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dDate = txtA_DateCR.Value
End Sub

'Supposed to change the textbox values to light grey and have the value of dd/mm/yyyy
Private Sub txtA_DateCR_AfterUpdate()

    With txtA_DateCR
    If .Text = "" Then
    .ForeColor = &HC0C0C0
    .Text = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End If
    End With

End Sub

'When user clicks here, the value of dd/mm/yyyy will disappear and font colour will return back to black
Private Sub txtA_DateCR_Enter()

    With txtA_DateCR
    If .Text = "dd/mm/yyyy" Then
    .ForeColor = &H80000008
    .Text = ""
    End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

txtA_DateCR.ForeColor = &HC0C0C0
txtA_DateCR.Text = "dd/mm/yyyy"
cmdEnter.SetFocus

End Sub
```

[image: Before selection of Arrival Date]
[image: Arrival date selected]
[image: Clicked away from arrival date]

As a summary, I only want the error message to pop up if the user enters the format of date wrongly and not popup when I click away from the textbox.

Comment: Try doing your validation on the click event of the Enter button then.

Comment: Have you tryied to add ```If txtA_DateCR.Value = "" Then Exit Sub``` before ```If Mid(txtA_DateCR.Value, 4, 2) > 12 Then...```?

Comment: dees' method worked! Thanks both you guys! can't seem to  select correct answer for you though.  @dee

Comment: @Edward you won't be able to mark an answer unless someone actually provides an answer. Currently, they've been able to solve the issue with simple comment suggestion :)